# Как из фильтра передать управление сервлету?

Tags: java, java-ee, servlet

Есть сервлет `myServlet` и фильтр `MyFilter`, который перехватывает обращение к сервлету. После фильтра, как я понял, должен сначала отработать сервлет, после чего он передаёт уже управление в `jsp`, но не понимаю как ему
передать управление?

У меня получается только из фильтра сразу выдать `jsp`, если я перенаправляю запрос так:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("myJsp.jsp").forward(request , response);
```

В сервлете надо сделать пару важных вычислений.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

После того как в фильтре выполнили все необходимые действия просто передавайте управление далее по цепочке:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    // Выполняем действия...

    // Передаем управление далее
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

Последним элементом в цепочке и будет сервлет.

Comment: так не работает..

Comment: блин я переопределил только doGet() , спасибо, понял